# Interface with functions that take any type

Tags: c++, interface, polymorphism, c++17, c++-concepts

I would like to define an interface for a message pump that is able to send and receive messages with a type specified by the user, to communicate e.g. between a producer and consumer.

Currently I have done it like that:

```
template <typename Message>
struct message_pump
{
    virtual void send(Message &&) = 0;

    //! Blocks if no message is available.
    virtual Message receive() = 0;
};
```

Then I would like to use this `message_pump` interface as a member of an `active` class (the pattern from Herb Sutters' - "Prefer Using Active Objects Instead of Naked Threads"):

```
template <typename Message>
class active
{
  private:
    struct quit_message{};
    using MessageProxy = typename std::variant<Message, quit_message>;

    std::unique_ptr<message_pump<MessageProxy>> message_pump_impl;
    std::function<void(Message&&)> message_handler;
    std::thread worker_thread;

    void thread_code() {
        while(true)
        {
            auto m{message_pump_impl->receive()};
            if(std::holds_alternative<quit_message>(m))
                break;
            message_handler(std::move(std::get<Message>(m)));
        }
    }

  public:
    active(std::unique_ptr<message_pump<MessageProxy>> message_pump_impl,
           std::function<void(Message&&)> message_handler) : 
               message_pump_impl{std::move(message_pump_impl)},
               message_handler{message_handler},
               worker_thread{[this](){ this->thread_code(); }} {}

};
```

The problem here is that static and dynamic polymorphism doesn't mix well and it's not possible to inject the implementation of the `message_pump` without knowing the type of the underlying `Message`.

The reason I'm doing this `active` class is that that I would like to reuse it across various RTOSes, which provide different `queue` and `thread` class implementations, and still be able to test it on the local computer. (I've put in this listing `std::thread` just for simplification, because how to make the `thread` implementation injectable is a different topic).

The question is what's the preferred way - the most OOP and "as it should be done" way - to define the interface `message_pump`, to be able to easily inject the implementation to the `active` class?

I have a few solutions in mind:

1. Define `struct message {}` inside `message_pump` and make `MessageProxy` a struct which inherits from the `message_pump::message`. Then return `std::unique_ptr<message>` from the `receive()` interface function.
2. Use `std::any` instead of `Message` inside `MessagePump`.
3. Use static polymorphism and inject `message_pump` implementation through a template parameter. Then the `message_pump` interface is not needed to be defined explicitly and we will get compiler errors if the implementer doesn't have a specific function.
4. Use C++20 concepts? (I would like also to know how to solve it with C++17).
5. Mix Ad.4 and Ad.5: use template parameter but explicitly define what interface it shall implement.
6. Other?

Comment: One issue, how would a user of this class be able to provide a `MessageProxy` when one of the types the `std::variant` holds is the `private struct quite_message`?

Comment: Exactly, this is what I'm asking for :)

Comment: I can imagine that `message_pump<int>` might have specializations on certain RTOS, so I'm wondering if OOP is the best solution. But that is already tricky with `quit_message`. Perhaps a `catch(quit_message)` instead?

Comment: OK, I think you can use `Type Erasure` here.

Comment: OK, I updated my answer to show how you can use `type erasure` with `opaque pointers` to hide the implementation details of both messages and message pumps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use dynamic polymorphism. This works, however, it requires the `active` type to expose what type it uses internally to hold the messages so that the right type of queue can be constructed.
2. Define `struct message {}` inside `message_pump` and make `MessageProxy` a struct which inherits from the `message_pump::message`. This doesn't gain us anything if we are using dynamic polymorphism. However, if using static polymorphism user messages can derive from  `active::message` which can derive from `message_pump::message`, which makes it possible to add non-movable messages without "emplace" methods. Having to derive messages from `active::message` is a down-side that shouldn't be overlooked especially if a message could reuse an existing type such as `int` otherwise. This will also require the messages to be dynamically allocated even for queues that wouldn't normally require this.
3. Use `std::any` instead of `Message` inside `MessagePump`. If using dynamic polymorphism, it fixes the problem with `active` having to expose what type of messages it uses internally and allows `active` to not be a template. But losses static type checking and has runtime overhead. I wouldn't recommend this as static type checking can make refactoring a lot less error prone.
4. Use static polymorphism and inject `message_pump` implementation through a template parameter. If `message_pump` is a template template parameter, `active` won't have to expose what type of messages it uses internally. This is similar to the approach taken by the standard library. However, the error messages can be hard to understand.
5. Use C++20 concepts? (I would like also to know how to solve it with C++17). concepts can help document what methods a `message_pump` would need and might give better errors. I wouldn't try anything like this with c++17, as the c++17 versions tend to be hard to read and give little benefit in this case.
6. use template parameter but explicitly define what interface it shall implement. Basically what concepts are meant to achieve.
7. Other? implement a queue that works on multiple platforms perhaps using `#ifdef` and have `active` use that queue or default `active`'s `message_pump` template parameter to that queue.

Comment: Ad. 6 How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

OK, you can use type erasure and opaque pointers in order to hide the details about both the message pump and message.

```
struct Message { std::string payload{ "Hello" }; };

struct VTable
{
    void* ( *Receive )( void* ptr );
    void  ( *Send )( void* ptr, void* message );
    void  ( *Destroy_ )( void* ptr );
    void* ( *Clone_ )( void* ptr );
    void* ( *MoveClone_ )( void* ptr );
};

template<typename T>
constexpr VTable VTableFor
{
    [ ]( void* ptr ) -> void* { return static_cast<T*>( ptr )->Receive( ); },
    [ ]( void* ptr, void* message ) { static_cast<T*>( ptr )->Send( message ); },
    [ ]( void* ptr ) { delete static_cast<T*>( ptr ); },
    [ ]( void* ptr ) -> void* { return new T{ *static_cast<T*>( ptr ) }; },
    [ ]( void* ptr ) -> void* { return new T{ std::move( *static_cast<T*>( ptr ) ) }; }
};


struct MessagePump 
{
    void* concrete_;
    const VTable* vtable_;

    template<typename T>
    MessagePump( T&& t ) 
        : concrete_( new T{ std::forward<T>( t ) } ),
          vtable_{ &VTableFor<T> } { }

    MessagePump( const MessagePump& rhs ) noexcept
        : concrete_{ rhs.vtable_->Clone_( rhs.concrete_ ) },
          vtable_{ rhs.vtable_ } { }

    MessagePump( MessagePump&& rhs ) noexcept
        : concrete_{ rhs.vtable_->MoveClone_( rhs.concrete_ ) },
          vtable_{ rhs.vtable_ } { }

    MessagePump& operator=( MessagePump rhs ) noexcept
    {
        swap( *this, rhs );      
        return *this;
    }

    friend void swap( MessagePump& lhs, MessagePump& rhs ) noexcept
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap( lhs.concrete_, rhs.concrete_ );
        swap( lhs.vtable_, rhs.vtable_ );
    }

    void* Receive( ) { return vtable_->Receive( concrete_ ); }

    void Send( void* message ) { vtable_->Send( concrete_, message ); }

    ~MessagePump( ) { vtable_->Destroy_( concrete_ ); }
};

struct CustomPump
{
    void* Receive( ) 
    { return new Message{ }; };

    void Send( void* message )
    {
        auto ptr{ static_cast<Message*>( message ) };
        std::cout << "Sending: " << ptr->payload << '\n';
        delete ptr;
    }
};

template<typename MessageType>
class Active
{
public:
    using Callback = void( * )( MessageType* msg );

    Active( MessagePump pump, Callback cb )
        : pump_{ std::move( pump ) },
          cb_{ cb } { }

    void Start( )
    {
        while ( true )
        {
            auto message{ pump_.Receive( ) };
            if ( !message )
            {
                std::cout << "No message\n";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                auto message{ static_cast<MessageType*>( result ) };
                std::invoke( cb_, message );
                pump_.Send( message );
            } 
        }
    }
private:
    MessagePump pump_;
    Callback cb_;
};


int main ( )
{
    Active<Message> active{ CustomPump{ }, 
        [ ]( Message* msg ){ std::cout << "Received: " << msg->payload << '\n'; } };
    active.Start( );
}
```